# How to get know if a checkbox has been selected in a dynamic UI in codenameone

Tags: checkbox, codenameone

I have a container with dynamic UI components including checkboxes. How can I know the selection status of a particular component?

Using `isSelected()` doesn't work as it is always false because it seems to pick the last checkbox in the list which returns false since it is unselected.

```
bool_isMemberSelected = cb_member.isSelected();  //returns false.
```

I am able to get the checkbox at a particular index in the parent component but once I have it there is no `isSelected` option on it. So I use a dirty way by tokenizing the string representing the component to get to the selected status. There must be a better way.

```
System.out.println("Checkbox Data "+cnt_tablerow[Integer.parseInt(lbl_memberno.getName())].getComponentAt(0)); //Checkbox Data: CheckBox[x=0 y=0 width=63 height=152 name=524, text = , gap = 2, selected = true]

String str_chkbox = StringUtil.tokenize(StringUtil.tokenize(cnt_tablerow[Integer.parseInt(lbl_memberno.getName())].getComponentAt(0), ']').get(0), '[').get(1);

String str_status = StringUtil.tokenize(StringUtil.tokenize(str_chkbox, ',').get(3), '=').get(1).trim();

if(str_status == "true"){}
```

Comment: `isSelected()` will return true for any selected check box. In the case of a radio button only one in a group can be selected. You might be confusing this with hasFocus. You can also use this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/button-lists.html

Comment: *"I am able to get the checkbox at a particular index in the parent component but once I have it there is no isSelected option on it."* - This sounds like you gett a `Component` back and forget to cast it to a `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate and set a `name` for each component when generating your dynamic UI. With a name you can use the [`ComponentSelector` API](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/ComponentSelector.html) or a simple `for` to get the `Checkbox` you want and then use the `isSelected` method.

If you want to keep your actual selection logic with the index, you can simply check the instance of your component and cast it to a `CheckBox`, that would also do the trick.